# Error code: 19. Only boots through recovery menu

Tags: boot

I did a fresh install of 22.04.3 and when I try to boot it gives me this error: hub 8-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)

I tried updating the kernal to 22.04 but I still have the same issue. I also tried reinstalling the OS but it gives me the same error code.

I am able to boot using the recovery menu but when I restart and use standard boot, it gives me this error. What could be the issue?

PC:
Ryzen 9 7900x
ASUS ROG-STRIX B550-F Gaming
G.Skill Ripjaw S5 DDR5 6000 32GB
RTX 3060ti

Comment: Have you been able to figure it out? I'm also getting a similar error. Instead of "hub 8-0:1.0" I'm getting "hbu 12-0:1.0" With Ryzen 9 7900, MSI X670E ACE (MS-7D69) and BIOS Version: E7D69AMS.190. 

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484830/hbu-12-01-0-config-failed-hub-doesnt-have-any-ports-error-19