# hbu 12-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (error -19)

Tags: kernel, 22.04, live-usb, 22.10, amd-ryzen

I recently built a PC with the following specifications:

- Processor: Ryzen 9 7900
- Motherboard: MSI X670E ACE (MS-7D69)
- BIOS Version: E7D69AMS.190
- RAM: 16GB x 2 Crucial
- Storage: 1 TB WD SSD

I encountered an issue when attempting to boot from the Ubuntu 22.04.3 bootable disk. The error message I received is as follows:

```
hbu 12-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (error -19)
```

I've tried several troubleshooting steps, including:

- Creating a fresh bootable USB.
- Reconfiguring RAM in different slots.
- Switching the SSD to different slots.
- Disabling Secure Boot.

Despite these efforts, I'm still encountering the same error.
Interestingly, I was able to successfully install Windows 10 on the
same system.

I did search for similar issues on this forum, but most of them seem to involve problems during the initial boot. In my case, I'm unable to install Ubuntu at all.

Could someone please guide me in the right direction to resolve this issue?

Thank you for your assistance.

**EDIT 1:**
I believe this issue may be related to USB-C, as I came across a similar question where a user was encountering a related error:

```
hub 6-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)
```

You can find the question and details at this link: [USB-C Ports Suddenly Stopped Working on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484724/usb-c-ports-suddenly-stopped-working-ubuntu-22-04)

I'm curious if there's a way to instruct Ubuntu to ignore or handle unsupported ports. Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 2:**
This answer ([Link to Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1478140/1568463)) prompted me to consider changing the kernel version. I attempted to find resources on creating an Ubuntu bootable with a specific kernel but couldn't find any useful information. Consequently, I decided to create a bootable with Ubuntu 22.10.

Using the Ubuntu 22.10 bootable, I encountered the same error, but it did proceed with the boot process. (I haven't completed the installation process yet; I'll provide an update later.) This leads me to believe that the issue could be related to the kernel version.

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 bootable has a kernel version of 6.2.0-26-generic.
- Ubuntu 22.10 bootable has a kernel version of 5.19.0-21-generic.

**EDIT 3:**
So I've been using Ubuntu 22.10 for a while now, and I keep encountering the error message "`config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (error -19)`" every time I turn on the system. Despite this error, I am still able to use the system with Ubuntu 22.10. For now, I will continue using it, but I would like to understand what causes this issue and how to run Ubuntu 22 with kernel version 6.

Additionally, when attempting to install Ubuntu 23, I encountered the same error message mentioned above and was unable to complete the installation.

Comment: Thanks for your report. I have the exact same message (`dmesg  | grep hub`) on `Linux neuf 6.1.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.52-1 (2023-09-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux` on a AMD Ryzen 5 7600 - Ryzen 5 7000 Series 6-Core 3.8 GHz Socket AM5 65W AMD Radeon Graphics Processor - 100-100001015BOX. It does not seem to be blocking, but I'd like to understand it better.

Comment: What is the `dmesg` after you reset the USB controller with https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245184/524752 ?